# How to remove the margin in a antd drawer

Tags: css, antd

[image]

I use a antd drawer.
The margin left and right of the drawer couldn't be removed, so the steps component is pushed a few margins from left and right (red circle).

Then, The antd steps blue slider is also has a margin (green circle).

I tried putting `margin:0px` and `padding:0px` but doesn't seems to fix these issues.

Code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-antd-4-19-5-forked-iq13nx?file=/index.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want remove the red margin, you need set padding left and right to 0 and remain the 24px in vertical sides:

```
.ant-drawer-body {
    flex-grow: 1;
    padding: 24px 0; // <-- This 0 do the work
    overflow: auto;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.5715;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

For the blue underscore (your green signal in the image), you must change this style:

```
.ant-menu-horizontal > .ant-menu-item::after, .ant-menu-horizontal > .ant-menu-submenu::after {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0; // <-- 0 instead 20px
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0; // <-- 0 instead 20px
    border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
    transition: border-color 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
    content: '';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the use the `Drawer` props "`bodyStyle`" to modify the style of the body:

```
        <Drawer          
          bodyStyle={{ padding:'0px' }}
        >
//...
        </Drawer>
```